# Fraction line vs stroke

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, terminology

In mathematical fractions, what is the correct and proper term (in British English in case of more variants) for the horizontal division line between the numerator and the denominator?

What I find in dictionaries is

> Fraction line
>   Stroke
>   Fraction stroke

None of these appear in the [Oxford Lexico dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/stroke), though, so I am in doubt. Which is a proper term that is used in English-speaking schools?

Answer (score 1):

In a fraction where the numerator is above a horizontal line, and the denominator below it, the horizontal line is usually called a fraction bar or, occasionally, a vinculum.

[Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Notation)

Comment: Be wary of using *vinculum*, though, as it is more typically used to refer to an over- or underline (for example, in repeating decimals).